# document.execCommand of insertText not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to so hard to dig out the solution to my problem from last week. `document.execCommand('insertText', false, emo)` this code line is working for all browser except IE (Internet Explorer
11). For IE, I have written the method `insertTextAtCursor` which is inserting always first in content editable.

> My problem is, How could I insert the text into contentEditable at the cursor point for IE? Thanks in advance.

```
var insertTextAtCursor = function (html) {
    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
      // IE9 and non-IE
      sel = window.getSelection();
      if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();

        // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but is
        // non-standard and not supported in all browsers (IE9, for one)
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.innerText = html;
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
        while ((node = el.firstChild)) {
          lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
        }
        range.insertNode(frag);

        // Preserve the selection
        if (lastNode) {
          range = range.cloneRange();
          range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
          range.collapse(false);
          sel.removeAllRanges();
          sel.addRange(range);
        }
      }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
      // IE < 9
      document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Except for _which_ IE? There's a lot of them, and only one of them is still supported by Microsoft.

Comment: Basically I am working on Internet Explorer 11, Do you have any idea to figure out this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Please put that information in your post. As far as I know, execCommand is fully supported in IE11, so you might need to start reducing your code to see exactly which line of code is failing, because it seems unlikely that you need _all_ this code to have others reproduce this problem.

Comment: I already do that bro, Thank you for your guideline.

Answer (score 0):

> document.execCommand('insertText', false, emo)

Not found the above code from the insertTextAtCursor function, when and where you are using the insertTextAtCursor function and the execCommand method? From [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand), it seems that the execCommand method support IE browser. And, I have create a sample using your code, it seems that everything works well, please check it:

```
<div id="thing" contenteditable="true" style="width:200px; border :1px solid black; cursor:pointer">
    this is a some random foo bar jumps over a stick test
</div>

<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="insertTextAtCursor('aaaa');" />
<script>
    var insertTextAtCursor = function (html) {
        var sel, range;
        if (window.getSelection) {
            // IE9 and non-IE
            sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
                range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                range.deleteContents();

                // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but is
                // non-standard and not supported in all browsers (IE9, for one)
                var el = document.createElement("div");
                el.innerText = html;
                var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
                while ((node = el.firstChild)) {
                    lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
                }
                range.insertNode(frag);

                // Preserve the selection
                if (lastNode) {
                    range = range.cloneRange();
                    range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                    range.collapse(false);
                    sel.removeAllRanges();
                    sel.addRange(range);
                }
            }
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
            // IE < 9
            document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
        }
    };
</script>
```

The output as below:

[image]